# multisite 404 subfolder same name slug as site

Tags: multisite, redirect, htaccess, 404-error, slug

*To keep this short, as a disclaimer, I'm not that versed with WordPress, servers, etc, so I might talk gibberish:*

**The Issue**

I have a multisite root, let's call it *msite.com*

This site spawns temporary subsites with a random slug *msite.com/random-code* . This means I can't possibly know the slug beforehand

I also need to have on the server a folder with the random-site's slug name

`(for example, on the server, the directory structure will be as follows: mysite.com/<random-code>)`

The problem is, if there's a folder as the slug, the server throw's a 404 as it expects to reach an index.php in that folder and not be redirected to WordPress

---

**What I found out**

Well, looking at the [generic .htaccess for a multisite](https://gist.github.com/domantasg/c68a3e8d180006efde3e5797a89e738f), I realized this condition is the issue:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

It basically blocks any attempt if there's an existing folder.

So naturally, I deleted it. Or more like made it

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

And it works fine ...

**Alas, why it was there in the first place?**

I want things to run smooth, so this probably causes an issue so I want to double-check if so and if there is a better solution

*Also, a related question out of pure curiosity, how folders like wp-admin where able to bypass that rule*

Comment: "if there's a folder as the slug, the server throw's a 404" - don't you mean a 403?

Comment: Well it was 404 written big in browser, I don't know the actual response code since i never looked at http response, but regardless, is it relevant?